# Generating json file in java. Code is working. Some modification help required

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, logic

I have to create json file in java. I can create json file when I pass parameter in where clause. I am reading data from Oracle database
Below is my Data.

[image]

When I send parameter `Select * from Data where tablename='ITEM'` then my code created file `ITEM.json` same for org.

Situation is tomorrow I dont know how many different tablename would be in TABLENAME column. for eg ITEM,ORG,FEATURE etc.
Can I create file in java by reading data without passing parameter. means in case of above data there should be 2 files. ITEM.json and ORG.json. I dont want to use `where clause` in query . my program should create file based on  data in the table.

I want data in below format.
ITEM.json

```
{"add":[{"canonicalName":"Apple Computers","synonyms":["Apple","Apple Inc"]},{"canonicalName":"Google India","synonyms":["Google"]},{"canonicalName":"IBM","synonyms":["IBM Corporation"]}],"update":[{"canonicalName":"Infosys","synonyms":["Infosys Tech"]},{"canonicalName":"Wipro Tech","synonyms":["Wipro Technology"]}],"delete":[{"canonicalName":"IBM","synonyms":["IBM Corporation"]},{"canonicalName":"TCS"}]}
```

ORG.json

```
{"add":[{"canonicalName":"Apple Computers","synonyms":["Apple","Apple Inc"]},{"canonicalName":"Google India","synonyms":["Google"]},{"canonicalName":"IBM","synonyms":["IBM Corporation"]}],"update":[{"canonicalName":"Infosys","synonyms":["Infosys Tech"]},{"canonicalName":"Wipro Tech","synonyms":["Wipro Technology"]}],"delete":[{"canonicalName":"IBM","synonyms":["IBM Corporation"]},{"canonicalName":"TCS"}]}
```

My below code is working properly but this works when I pass parameter `where TABLENAME='ITEM'` .same for ORG. I want my code to read table data and create file based on the unique values in TABLENAME column.

```
public  String createJsonFile(String dynamicEntityName) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Inside createJsonFile");
        String query="select * from dynamicentitygtt where tablename=?";
        PreparedStatement prepstatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        prepstatement.setString(1,dynamicEntityName);
        ResultSet rs=prepstatement.executeQuery();
        List<EntityDataNEW> dataList= new ArrayList<EntityDataNEW>();
        
        
        while(rs.next());
            {   
                EntityDataNEW entityData= new EntityDataNEW();
                String entityName=rs.getString("ORGNAME");
                String synonyms=rs.getString("SYNONYMS");
                entityData.setSynonyms(synonyms);
                entityData.setItemname(entityName);
                entityData.setOperation(rs.getString("OPERATION"));
                dataList.add(entityData);
            }

    
        JsonArrayBuilder add=Json.createArrayBuilder();
        JsonArrayBuilder delete=Json.createArrayBuilder();
        JsonArrayBuilder update=Json.createArrayBuilder();
        
        for(EntityDataNEW data: dataList)
        {
            
            switch(data.getOperation())
            {
            case "delete":
                JsonObjectBuilder deleteObj=Json.createObjectBuilder();
                JsonArrayBuilder deleteSynonyms=Json.createArrayBuilder();
                deleteObj.add("canonicalName", data.getItemname());
                deleteSynonyms.add(0,data.getSynonyms());
                deleteObj.add("synonyms", data.getSynonyms());
                deleteObj.add("synonyms", data.getSynonyms());
                delete.add(deleteObj);
                delete.add(deleteSynonyms);
                break;
                
            case "update":
                JsonObjectBuilder updateObj=Json.createObjectBuilder();
                JsonArrayBuilder modifySynonyms=Json.createArrayBuilder();
                updateObj.add("canonicalName", data.getItemname());
                modifySynonyms.add(0,data.getSynonyms());
                updateObj.add("synonyms", data.getSynonyms());
                update.add(updateObj);
                update.add(modifySynonyms);
                break;
                
            case "add":
                JsonObjectBuilder addObj=Json.createObjectBuilder();
                JsonArrayBuilder addSynonyms=Json.createArrayBuilder();
                addObj.add("canonicalName", data.getItemname());
                addSynonyms.add(0,data.getSynonyms());
                addObj.add("synonyms",addSynonyms);
                add.add(addObj);
                add.add(addSynonyms);
                break;  
                
            default:
                break;
            
            
            }
            rs.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        
        JsonObjectBuilder mainObj= Json.createObjectBuilder();
        mainObj.add("delete",delete);
        mainObj.add("update", update);
        mainObj.add("add",add);
        String data = mainObj.build().toString();
        System.out.println(data);
        String filePath= ODAParams.ENTITY_FILE_PATH+"/"+dynamicEntityName+".json";
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("End of file writing code");
        return filePath;
      }

EntityDataNEW is my POJO class.
```

Can I create 2 different file based on data without passing TABLENAME in where clause

Comment: When the requirement is to categorize based on `TABLENAME`. Why don't you go with `Group By` expression?

Comment: will data also come with group by expression?

Comment: It will just give distinct tablename , is it possible to give data as well? can you suggest changes in above code please?

Comment: In your second question about this problem in the last two days (I believe you are up to four questions so far at least), I showed you how to get an output with each unique `TABLENAME` in one row, with the corresponding JSON document (for that `TABLENAME`) in a second column. From that result, it would be trivial to generate actual text files using pretty much any tools. Why are you going the parameterized query route?

Comment: @mathguy thank you so much for kind help mathguy . Actually I am not able to return that data in java. I have to inject that data into API using jersey client.

Answer (score 0):

Using this **`SELECT * from Data GROUP BY tablename`**, you can get record group by table name.

Now according to table name you need to create entityList like if table name is **`ORG`** than **`orgEntityList`**  if name is **`ITEM`**  then **`itemEntityList`**.

```
  public  String createJsonFile(String dynamicEntityName) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Inside createJsonFile");
        String query="select * from dynamicentitygtt GROUP BY tablename";
        PreparedStatement prepstatement=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        prepstatement.setString(1,dynamicEntityName);
        ResultSet rs=prepstatement.executeQuery();
        List<EntityDataNEW> dataList= new ArrayList<EntityDataNEW>();

        String previousTableName=null;
        while(rs.next());
        {
            EntityDataNEW entityData= new EntityDataNEW();
            String tableName=rs.getString("TABLENAME");
            if(previousTableName != null && !tableName.equalsIgnoreCase(previousTableName)){
                entityData= new EntityDataNEW();
            }
            String entityName=rs.getString("ORGNAME");
            String synonyms=rs.getString("SYNONYMS");
            entityData.setSynonyms(synonyms);
            entityData.setItemname(entityName);
            entityData.setOperation(rs.getString("OPERATION"));
            dataList.add(entityData);
            previousTableName=tableName;
        }


        JsonArrayBuilder add=Json.createArrayBuilder();
        JsonArrayBuilder delete=Json.createArrayBuilder();
        JsonArrayBuilder update=Json.createArrayBuilder();

        for(EntityDataNEW data: dataList)
        {

            switch(data.getOperation())
            {
                case "delete":
                    JsonObjectBuilder deleteObj=Json.createObjectBuilder();
                    JsonArrayBuilder deleteSynonyms=Json.createArrayBuilder();
                    deleteObj.add("canonicalName", data.getItemname());
                    deleteSynonyms.add(0,data.getSynonyms());
                    deleteObj.add("synonyms", data.getSynonyms());
                    deleteObj.add("synonyms", data.getSynonyms());
                    delete.add(deleteObj);
                    delete.add(deleteSynonyms);
                    break;

                case "update":
                    JsonObjectBuilder updateObj=Json.createObjectBuilder();
                    JsonArrayBuilder modifySynonyms=Json.createArrayBuilder();
                    updateObj.add("canonicalName", data.getItemname());
                    modifySynonyms.add(0,data.getSynonyms());
                    updateObj.add("synonyms", data.getSynonyms());
                    update.add(updateObj);
                    update.add(modifySynonyms);
                    break;

                case "add":
                    JsonObjectBuilder addObj=Json.createObjectBuilder();
                    JsonArrayBuilder addSynonyms=Json.createArrayBuilder();
                    addObj.add("canonicalName", data.getItemname());
                    addSynonyms.add(0,data.getSynonyms());
                    addObj.add("synonyms",addSynonyms);
                    add.add(addObj);
                    add.add(addSynonyms);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;


            }
            rs.close();
            connection.close();
        }

        JsonObjectBuilder mainObj= Json.createObjectBuilder();
        mainObj.add("delete",delete);
        mainObj.add("update", update);
        mainObj.add("add",add);
        String data = mainObj.build().toString();
        System.out.println(data);
        String filePath= ODAParams.ENTITY_FILE_PATH+"/"+dynamicEntityName+".json";
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("End of file writing code");
        return filePath;
    }


// I am putting this query here as not able to put in comment with format
SELECT DISTINCT DATA.* FROM DATA 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT TABLENAME FROM SAMPLE.Data GROUP BY TABLENAME
)X ON X.TABLENAME=DATA.TABLENAME;
```

If you see above code, it's applying query with **`GROUP BY`**.

Comment: Thank you Sagar, I am going through the same.

Comment: @Shruti ,Great..!!

Comment: this code will not work Sagar. this query itself will not work. If I use column name in select query then I will not get data of all columns,   "select * from dynamicentitygtt GROUP BY entity_type

Comment: thank you @Sagar . I have zoom. if you can help I would be happy to connect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220326/discussion-between-sagar-gangwal-and-shruti).

Comment: Sorry Sagar, I saw very late this ping. i will ping you today probably in evening india time.